# Spring Boot JPA Insert and Update

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, sql-insert, h2

Alright, I've looked around to find this answer for about an hour and I can't see it posted. So I bought the Spring Framework Master Class from in28minutes on Udemy. We have started implementing JPA. However, the Spring Boot versions are different( he is using 2.0.3, I am using 2.4.0). Now I know that's the issue. So the task is to simply connect to a h2 database, and interact with the data. Here is the current code setup I am using:

**JpaDemoApplication.java**

```
package com.in28minutes.database.databasedemo;

import java.util.Date;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.in28minutes.database.databasedemo.entity.Person;
import com.in28minutes.database.databasedemo.jpa.PersonJpaRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JpaDemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    PersonJpaRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpaDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        
        logger.info("User id 10001 -> {}", repository.findById(10001));
        
        logger.info("Inserting -> {}", 
                repository.insert(new Person("Tara", "Berlin", new Date())));
        /*
        logger.info("Update 10003 -> {}", 
                repository.update(new Person(10003, "Pieter", "Utrecht", new Date())));
        
        //repository.deleteById(10002);

        logger.info("All users -> {}", repository.findAll());
        */
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="find_all_persons", query="select p from Person p")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private Date birthDate;

    public Person() {}

    public Person(int id, String name, String location, Date birthDate) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public Person(String name, String location, Date birthDate) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public int getId() { return id;}
    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public String getLocation() {return location;}
    public void setLocation(String location) {this.location = location;}
    public Date getBirthDate() {return birthDate;}
    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {this.birthDate = birthDate;}
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("\nPerson [id=%s, name=%s, location=%s, birthDate=%s]", id, name, location, birthDate);
    }
}
```

**PersonJpaRepository.java**

```
package com.in28minutes.database.databasedemo.jpa;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.in28minutes.database.databasedemo.entity.Person;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonJpaRepository {

    // connect to the database
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Person> findAll() {
        TypedQuery<Person> namedQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("find_all_persons", Person.class);
        return namedQuery.getResultList();
    }

    public Person findById(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(Person.class, id);// JPA
    }

    public Person update(Person person) {
        return entityManager.merge(person);
    }

    public Person insert(Person person) {
        return entityManager.merge(person);
    }

    public void deleteById(int id) {
        Person person = findById(id);
        entityManager.remove(person);
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#logging.level.root=debug
#spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default
```

**data.sql**

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, NAME, LOCATION, BIRTH_DATE)
VALUES(10001, 'Ranga', 'Hyderabad', sysdate());
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, NAME, LOCATION, BIRTH_DATE)
VALUES(10002, 'James', 'New York', sysdate());
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, NAME, LOCATION, BIRTH_DATE)
VALUES(10003, 'Pieter', 'Amsterdam', sysdate());
```

**schema.sql**

```
create table person
(
    id integer not null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    location varchar(255),
    birth_date timestamp,
    primary key(id)
);
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.in28minutes.database</groupId>
    <artifactId>database-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>database-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I know this is a lot, but I am very new to Spring, and I HAVE to have this down by January, due to me starting a new job. The specific error is that the table is created, the first select by id works, but the insert passes a null value:

```
Hibernate: insert into person (id, birth_date, location, name) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
2020-12-03 10:59:16.724  WARN 14464 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502
2020-12-03 10:59:16.724 ERROR 14464 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into person (id, birth_date, location, name) values (null, ?, ?, ?) [23502-200]
```

I have tried 5 different suggestions, but none have worked. What am I doing wrong? Pointing to something that can explain how to do it works as well, I'm always looking for more current learning resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `@GeneratedValue` annotation is used to generate primary key value automatically. There are 4 generation types: **AUTO**, **IDENTITY**, **SEQUENCE**, **TABLE**.
- ***AUTO***: The persistence provider will determine values based on the type of the primary key attribute. `Numeric` values are generated based on a sequence generator and `UUID` values use the `UUIDGenerator`.
- ***IDENTITY***: It relies on the value generated by an identity column in the database, meaning they are auto-incremented. Note that **IDENTITY** generation disables batch updates.

You are using **IDENTITY** strategy without an `identity` column in your schema. Change the `schema.sql` as follows:

```
create table person
(
    id integer generated by default as identity not null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    location varchar(255),
    birth_date timestamp,
    primary key(id)
);
```

Comment: So that actually worked, so thank you! I will now tear it down and try to figure out how that worked, but at least now I have a starting point!